# Windows Form application does not run on windows 10

Tags: winforms, windows-10, compatibility

i am running an .exe file of windows form application through windows scheduler.
it appears on all machines but machines with windows 10. when i run .exe file on windows 10 machine it works fine but from schedular job it does not appear.

Comment: Insufficient access rights probably. What does task history show? And your question is not related to programming :(

Comment: its related to deployment, nothing appears in logs. i have developed an application that is executed by Task Scheduler. Application appears on other operating systems but not on windows 10. may be compatibility issue.

Comment: Task history (in Task Scheduler) is never empty, unless task is never executed. Have you ticked 'Run with highest privileges' in Task settings?

Comment: XP Compatibility Mode?

Comment: not sure, thats what i am looking into. it works when i click exe directly, issue occurs when i run exe through task schedular

Comment: @nabuchodonossor do i need to check XP Compatibility? i am talking about Windows 10 here.

Comment: @MTayyab: You should set the compatibility mode of the exe to "XP mode". This feature exists since Vista times ....